# Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined: d3 Choropleth

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm throwing the error **"Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined"** on the below chunk of code.  Does that mean the us.json file isn't loading?  I tested it with a console log, and it does appear to be loading properly, and there *is* an `objects` property, so what's going wrong?

```
queue()

  // Load map JSON
  .defer(d3.json, 
  'https://rawgit.com/HyperrealTech/thorn-directives/master/lib/us.json')

  // Load applicable data
  .defer(d3.json, data)

  // Call rateById for each d in data
  .await(function(d) { 
    rateById.set(d.state, +d.count); 
  })

  // Once finished loading, call ready function
  .await(ready);

  // Ready function
  function ready(error, us) {

    // Sum values in data to arrive at total
    var total = 0;
    for(var value in rateById) {
      if(rateById.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
        total += parseInt(rateById[value], 10);
      }
    }

    // Append states to svg
    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'states')
      .selectAll('path')

      // Error here
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
```